# `projectile-run-project` waits for compilation instead of running project

Tags: projectile

When I try to run my projectile project with `projectile-run-project` it prompts me for a run command. After running the command `./out.a` it opens a `*compilation*` buffer and hangs because it's trying to compile with the run command I just entered, so it waits for the command to finish. I have to run `kill-compilation` to stop it.

Why is the run command used to compile instead to just run the project? And how to make it actually run?

Comment: It sounds like it’s working correctly. `projectile-configure-project`, `projectile-compile-project`, `projectile-test-project`, and other such functions all just run a command and wait for it to finish. The output is shown in a `*compilation*` buffer, but that doesn’t mean that it’s compiling. All of them wait for the command they are running to exit. Does your program not exit? Does it not produce output? What else are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @db48x Since the buffer for running a project says "Compiling project" i thought that the command was supposed to recompile and run a command. But apparently not. Should I open a low priority issue on github for changing the string to show "Running project..."?